# Format string value datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, format, datagridviewcellstyle

I am looking to format a value in a datagridview.
These values are a string containing a decimal number. (Like "3000"
I want to display it with a thousand separator (space), like this: "3,000".

I know it can be done by assigning format of defaultcellstyle using format like "N2" for example, this works with decimal column type but 
I'm using a string column type in my datagridview to handle some exception(displaying "-" instead of "0" to simplify users view)

I tried differents cell style format and nothing changed in the display.

do i need to change the column type of my datagridview or it can be done without too much code ?

Thanks for all reply,

Tristan

Comment: Try the [CellFormatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: i'm trying it right now, can't make it work as i expect for the moment.

Comment: You would have to post your code.  Click the edit link below your post.

Comment: i just made it working  as i expected. i will complete my question with an answer with the right code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just made it working  as i expected. i did the commented things first and it just showed errors, so i tried the second way (simpliest) that is not commented.

```
string value = cell.Value.ToString();
//NumberFormatInfo nfi =(NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
//nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
//string formatted = double.Parse(value).ToString("n", nfi);
//cell.Value = formatted.Replace(".00","");// 12 345.00
string formatted = double.Parse(value).ToString("# ### ###");
cell.Value = formatted;
```

Comment: Nice. Will try this.